# How to display a confirmationDialog in dark mode?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, darkmode

When switching the application to dark mode, the `confirmationDialog` is displayed in white. How can I make the `confirmationDialog` also show up in dark mode?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingListView: View, Themeable {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var showingConfirmation = false
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode = false
    @StateObject var settingsListViewModel = SettingsListViewModel()
    @State private var changeValueID = true
    @State private var showContacts = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    VStack {
                        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                            Image("avatar")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    showingConfirmation = true
                                }
                                .confirmationDialog("Change Profile Picture", isPresented: $showingConfirmation, titleVisibility: .visible) {
                                    Button(role: .none, action: {}) {
                                        Text("Take Photo")
                                    }
                                    Button(role: .none, action: {}) {
                                        Text("Choose from library")
                                    }
                                    Button(role: .none, action: {}) {
                                        Text("Use Avatar")
                                    }
                                }
                            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                                .foregroundColor(isDarkMode ? .white : .black)
                                .frame(width: 28, height: 28)
                                .background(isDarkMode ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.370555222, green: 0.3705646992, blue: 0.3705595732, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)))
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .overlay {
                                    Circle().stroke(isDarkMode ? .black : Color(.secondarySystemBackground), lineWidth: 4)
                                }
                                .scaleEffect(x: 1.1, y: 1.1, anchor: .center)
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Please see [ask] including the section on using text for code (not images). You'd also want to include a [mre].

Comment: Did you try just to omit the background color definition and let the OS use the default value?

Comment: Haven't tried. In Assets, I set the colors for the light and dark theme and thought that it would change colors everywhere.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change background color when dark mode turns on in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59694589/change-background-color-when-dark-mode-turns-on-in-swiftui)

Comment: Unfortunately no. I think only making a custom confirmationDialog will help here.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to to add the .preferredColorScheme()

```
@State private var isDarkMode = false
  Image(Avatar)
   .confirmationDialog(.....) {
    VStack {
      ....
    }
    .preferredColorScheme(isDarkMode ? .dark : .light)
   }
```

Something like that. May need to play with where the modifier is. I've never used it so Im not entirely sure where it would go.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
if colorScheme == .dark {

UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = .white

} else {

UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = .black

}
```

This works but it would make your entire `.confirmationDialog` of the same color.

Comment: When adding code, it gives an error "Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'". I'm new to this site and I don't know how to add code to the answer. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm just still a beginner.

Comment: add this inside an ```.onappear``` closure on your view.

Comment: @
lemonator21
Thanks, this helped. Only now the confirmationDialog appears differently, namely: all the buttons are located in one block. Prior to this, by default, the cancel button is at a small distance from other buttons. Also now the window appears without rounded corners.

Comment: What do you mean one block?
The only thing this changes is the color of all UIAlerts across your app.

Comment: It's possible to override SwiftUI functionality using UIKit.

Comment: @lemonator21 In addition to color, it has also changed in appearance. I have three buttons in my code:
"Change Profile Picture",
"Choose from library",
Use Avatar". They are located one after another. The "Cancel" button is located at a short distance from them. At the same time, the corners of the pop-up window are rounded. After adding the code, the distance between the "Cancel" button and other buttons disappeared. Also, the rounded corners of the pop-up window disappeared.
 It catches the eye. Other apps in dark mode don't have this problem.

Comment: @lemonator21 I think it is necessary to make a custom confirmationDialog. On the site I saw a guy do this just for alert. And everything worked great. Unfortunately, my knowledge is not enough to write it myself.

Comment: I see, well in that case you'll have to use UIAlertController instead.

Comment: all good, it's not good to include UIKit dependancies in a SwiftUI View but over here  it doesn't seem like there's any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading [colorScheme](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/colorscheme) correctly:

`@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme`

but then you don‘t use it.
Instead of your variable `isDarkMode`, use `colorScheme == .dark` in your color modifiers to adapt your view to the color scheme.

In your example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SettingListView: View, Themeable {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var showingConfirmation = false
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    // @AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var isDarkMode = false // not neccessary
    @StateObject var settingsListViewModel = SettingsListViewModel()
    @State private var changeValueID = true
    @State private var showContacts = true
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                Section {
                    VStack {
                        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                            Image("avatar")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    showingConfirmation = true
                                }
                                .confirmationDialog("Change Profile Picture", isPresented: $showingConfirmation, titleVisibility: .visible) {
                                    Button(role: .none, action: {}) {
                                        Text("Take Photo")
                                    }
                                    Button(role: .none, action: {}) {
                                        Text("Choose from library")
                                    }
                                    Button(role: .none, action: {}) {
                                        Text("Use Avatar")
                                    }
                                }
                            Image(systemName: "pencil")
                                .foregroundColor(colorScheme ? .white : .black) // use colorScheme
                                .frame(width: 28, height: 28)
                                .background(colorScheme ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.370555222, green: 0.3705646992, blue: 0.3705595732, alpha: 1)) : Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1))) // use colorScheme
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .overlay {
                                    Circle().stroke(isDarkMode ? .black : Color(.secondarySystemBackground), lineWidth: 4)
                                }
                                .scaleEffect(x: 1.1, y: 1.1, anchor: .center)
                        }
                    }
```

——-

**A simpler option** without reading environment value `colorScheme` is to leave color choice to the system with semantic colors:

```
 .foregroundColor(.primary)
```

Leave out .background(Color…) in that case